# How can I keep my user's login session open in my flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, session

in my application flutter after a user logs in, I would like the session to remain open. That is, if a user opens the app, he logs in, if he were to close the application and open it later I would like him to be still logged in and not have to re-enter his credentials.
I found this `flutter_session` library but I didn't understand if it's right for me or just to keep the session active between one page and another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using firebase there is still various option for this task. here's come local storage SharedPreference or GetStorage to store data (credential ) locally until user is logged in. and whenever user logout we will clear stored data.
visit this package https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage
when user first time login store credentials like

```
GetStorage box = GetStorage();

box.write('email',email.value);
```

When user logout, clear the data

```
box.remove('email');
```

and further when user launch the app we will check if email key has value in it then redirect to home screen or else Login Screen.

```
if(box.read('email')!='' || box.read('email')!=null)
  Get.to(HomeScreen());
else
  Get.to(LoginScreen());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how to do that. You didn't tell about the server you're using to accomplish that. If your'e using firebase for example, you can do it like this:

```
class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  AuthService auth = AuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    auth.getUser.then(
      (user) {
        if (user != null) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/topics');
        }
        else {
          //force to login page
       }
      },
    );
  }
```

You can get informations about the current user session inside the auth. This is the perfect entry point for user login sessions: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/

Comment: I use the app to connect users to odoo